# Could not cast value of type NavigationController to "Имя Вью контроллера"

Tags: ios

Задача:
Передаю картинку из одного вью контроллера в другой.
Картинка передается в переменную.

Вопрос:
Xcode просит использовать Navigator Controller перед каждым ViewController. Поэтому надо как-то переформулировать строку получения вью контроллера (1 в коде)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
//1  получаю вью контроллер, но ругается. **Could not cast value of type NavigationController to "Имя Вью контроллера"** 

let destinationVC: SaveAfterFilterScreen = segue.destinationViewController as! SaveAfterFilterScreen
destinationVC.tempImage = imageFromCamera!.image!
}
```

Comment: знакомая картинка :)

Comment: nav controller должен быть один, а не по одному на каждый VC, что то вы напутали

Answer (score 1):

В общем, я крутился вокруг Segue, и получал сообщение, что 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
an instance of UINavigationController.'

После того, как я исправил вид segue Push на modal, заработало.

Comment: и если вам надо еще один контроллер положить сверху, то будете два модальных один на один класть?

Answer (score 0):

1. Бери destinationViewController как UINavigationController.
2. Потом из этого navController бери topViewController as!
3. SaveAfterFilterScreen. Это и будет твоим destinationVC

PS: точно, вместо rootViewController нужно брать topViewController. Спасибо за замечание

Comment: А такого свойства   rootViewController  у  UINavigationController  нет.      Есть topViewController

Comment: Да, ***rootViewController*** нет, вместо него стоит использовать ***.viewControllers[0]***

Comment: у массива лучше брать firstObject - при работе с индексом желательно проверять размер массива.
PS: исправил проперти на topViewController